# How to send JSON format filter query in ajax request to elasticsearch

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch

I am new in elasticsearch and i am looking to explore filters in elsticsearch. I am sending following request to elasticsearch:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#btnSearch").on("click", function () {
            if ($("#txtSearchAllFields").val() != '') {
                var filter = {
                    "query": {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "default_field": "_all",
                                        "query": $ ("#txtSearchAllFields").val()
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "must_not": [],
                            "should": []
                        }
                    },
                    "from": 0,
                    "size": 250,
                    "sort": [],
                    "aggs": {}
                };

                GetEmployee(filter);
            }
        })

    });
    function GetEmployee(filter) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://easticsearchserver:9200/empmaster/_search",
            crossDomain: true,
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify(filter),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: OnSuccess,
            error: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }

    function OnSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $(data.hits.hits).each(function (index, hit) {

        });
    };
</script>
```

But i am getting Bad request error.

Please let me know how i can send this json query with this request.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "query": ("#txtSearchAllFields").val() in the must clause is missing the $.

Also, I don't think you want to be stringifying the filter object in the ajax request.

Comment: $ was missing by mistake. Do you have any experience in elasticsearch ajax request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, In ajax request method i was using "GET" but it should be "POST".
Issue is resolved now.

Thanks everyone.